# No user interaction after setting

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a very very old iPhone/iPad app, actually it was my very first Objective-C app, I started learning iOS programming on it. Now I want to update it a bit but have following problem:

The app has never had any viewController. When I started writing it, I wasn't familiar with MCV and Interface Builder. First version was just for iPhone and it made the UI manually by just positioning UILabels and UIButtons in UIApplicationDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** via addSubview directly into self.window (there is MainWindow.xib but it's empty). A couple of months later I created iPad version. It has all the UI created in Interface Builder in a single MainWindow_iPad.xib. There are no other xibs, just UILables and UIButtons placed directly in MainWindow_iPad.xib and no view controller was used again.

Now, a couple of years later, I want to update this veteran app a bit. I want to add a root view controller so I set window.rootViewController in UIApplicationDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**. I have no problem with the iPhone version, it works a treat. But I have troubles with the iPad one. After setting window.rootViewController, the **app doesn't interact to any touch at all**. It loads, the UI is created but it's just frozen.

Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks a lot!

Don't tell me I should throw it away and write it again from scratch in a normal "experienced way", I know this would be the best way but I don't need to update it that much to waste so much time.

Comment: Rewrite it from scratch. And leave that goddamn IB out, it screws things up. Create the UI from code.

Comment: Is that an universal app? Can you put some code on pastebin.com, or even here if it's less than 32 lines.

Comment: Yes it is universal app however each device has own application delegate and own UI so actually for this problem you can consider it to be two independent apps, one for iPhone and one for iPad, just using same data.